# When do I use MiniTest::Unit::TestCase versus MiniTest::Spec?

Tags: ruby, tdd, bdd

I've been learning TDD/BDD using MiniTest. What I'm trying to figure out is what parts of my code should be tested with MiniTest::Unit::TestCase and which parts should be tested using MiniTest::Spec.

I understand the difference between unit testing and integration testing, what I can't seem to grasp from examples across the web is whether or not a TestCase and a Spec are both unit tests or if a TestCase is used for a unit test and a Spec used for integration testing?

Should I keep my quick unit tests in MiniTest::Unit::TestCase classes and longer integration testing, which more often describe features, in MiniTest::Spec expectations? Does it even matter, or is it a question of personal preference?

Answer (score 4):

Whether I use [MiniTest::Unit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Unit.html) (with [assertions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html)) vs. [MiniTest::Spec](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/minitest/spec/rdoc/index.html), is determined by who I am writing them for.

For code I write myself, without any "customer" requirements, I'd use MiniTest::Unit. The tests make sense to me and reading them is terse and to the point.

If I'm writing code for a customer who has a list of requirements, I'd use MiniTest::Spec. The spec files are more readable to a non-programmer.

---

Note: MiniTest underwent an overhaul last year so some of the module names changed but the idea is the same, MiniTest supports a more terse, or more verbose, way of writing unit tests.

Comment: So they are essentially two different ways of doing the same thing? Just syntactically different... ?

Comment: Pretty much. There are a number of different "languages" for writing unit tests, and they boil down to different ways of saying the same thing. They add different layers of verbosity, aimed at different types of people. Developers tend to like the terseness of generic unit tests with assertions. For project managers and/or customers who don't "talk programming", Spec works better, or use something that says the same things in more common terms.